# Node js + TypeSc + Babel "Error: Cannot find module 'koa'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs

1. I have cloned a [demo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter) . after installing koa,koa-router etc, I got an error. Here is my index.ts file

```js
import Koa from "koa"
import Router from "koa-router"
import logger from "koa-logger"
import json from "koa-json"

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()

router.get("/",async(ctx: any,next: any)=>{
    ctx.body = {
        meg:"Hello world"
    }
    await next
})

app.use(logger())
app.use(json())
app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods())

app.listen(3000,()=>console.log("app is running at 3000"))
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "babel-typescript-sample",
  "version": "0.7.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "type-check:watch": "npm run type-check -- --watch",
    "build": "npm run build:types && npm run build:js",
    "build:types": "tsc --emitDeclarationOnly",
    "build:js": "babel src --out-dir lib --extensions \".ts,.tsx\" --source-maps inline"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
    "@types/koa": "^2.11.3",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "koa": "^2.11.0",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
    "koa-json": "^2.0.2",
    "koa-logger": "^3.2.1",
    "koa-router": "^8.0.8"
  }
}
```

my file structure loos like:

```
/-------
  -lib
    -index.js
    -index.d.ts
  -node_modules
  -src
    -index.ts
```

2. Actually,before this ,when I run `npm run build`,I got error `src/index.ts:2:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'koa-router'.` I write `koa-router.d.ts` myself, but I don't think it's a great idea, How do you guys resolve?

[image: struct]

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Install `koa-router` typings with `npm install --save-dev @types/koa-router`.
2. Set `moduleResolution` inside tsconfig.json to `node`. See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#module-resolution-strategies) for differences. Note that this option only works if the dependency has typings included. In this case, it does not, so first option would be more correct.
3. Edit `paths` (points to directory) or `types` (points to `.d.ts`) inside tsconfig.json to point to your typings. Yes, writing your typings ("by hand") for existing dependency is generally considered a bad idea, since it could update and therefore break your typings. If a dependency does not have typings, you can contribute to it by generating it using JSDoc, if it uses JavaScript.